# Mobify carousel direction

Tags: jquery, mobile, carousel, mobify

I am using [Mobify carousel](http://mobify.github.io/mobify-modules/carousel/) for a mobile template

When the direction is changed to rtl, the swipe is not working correctly. is there any fix for this?

Comment: Why have you done direction rtl, try text align right as this carousel is only created for ltr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using http://swipejs.com/ instead of mobyfy, it has out of the box left/right and right/left support

All you need to get started is something along the lines of

```
<div id='slider' class='swipe'>
  <div class='swipe-wrap'>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

window.mySwipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById('slider'), {
  startSlide: 2,
  speed: 400,
  auto: 3000,
  continuous: true,
  disableScroll: false,
  stopPropagation: false,
  callback: function(index, elem) {},
  transitionEnd: function(index, elem) {}
});
```

Comment: If swipejs doesn't strike your fancy, there's a bunch of them listed here http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/jquery-carousel-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

the issue was solved by changing left and right in the below code

```
if (dx > 0) {
self.prev();
} else {
self.next();
}
```